Laravel manage object based permission-ACL
I'm not very familiar with eloquent. I have two database schemas. I have tried both, with and without json field, but I can't find a solution to obtain:

all objects that the logged in user can modify;
if I select an object, check whether the logged in user can delete it;

Attached two database diagrams
db1
db2
I tried

with the scope withWhereHas in the Object model but I'm stuck on how to check permissions

Object::withWhereHas('roles', function($query) {
            $query->whereHas('users', function($query2){
                $query2->where('id',auth()->id());
            });

        });


with using('acls') in the Object model but I'm stuck on how to check permissions and and furthermore I also obtain objects not linked to the roles to which the logged in user belongs

Object::with(['roles' => function($query){`your text`
            $query->whereHas('users', function($query2){
                $query2->where('id',auth()->id());
            });
        }]);

I ask you for advice on the best procedure
